# Reading an append-only list from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to implement an append-only list in PostgreSQL. Basically, this is trivial: Create a table, and only ever `INSERT` into that table.

However, I would like to be able to read that list again, *in the order it was created*. How can I do this? Is a simple `SELECT * FROM MyTable` enough? If not, what do I sort by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows in a relational database have no inherent sort order. The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use an `order by`.

You can either create an identity column that is incremented on every insert or a `timestamp` column that records the precise time a row was inserted (or do both).

e.g.

```
create table append_only
(
   id bigint generated always as identity, 
   ... other columns ...
   created_at timestamp default clock_timestamp()
);
```

Then use that column for an `order by`. By having both, you can use the `id` column as a tie breaker when sorting by the timestamp in case two rows were inserted at exactly same microsecond.

Answer (score 0):

You could create  column with data type [SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)(similiar to AUTOINCREMENT/SEQUENCE):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(id SERIAL, ...)

SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: The problem with `SERIAL` is that it uses `SEQUENCE` behind the scenes, which is not part of transactions and which may hence lead to gaps in numbering (which I would like to avoid).

Comment: @GoloRoden Why  are you afraid of gaps, once you only need to establish an order?

Comment: Because that I only need the order was oversimplified . In the end, I don't want to have gaps because another part of the system needs to be able to detect records that have not been received, so here I want to use gaps to detect missing records. That's why I can't allow gaps to be in well-formed data.

Comment: @GoloRoden Stil you could use this column for ordering. Even though you could use two sequences  on the same table

Comment: @GoloRoden https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a8977036e01997011549d9b978d345e

Comment: Unfortunately, "GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY" also uses SEQUENCE behind the scenes. [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html). _GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY  ,,,
This clause creates the column as an identity column. It will have an implicit sequence attached to it and the column in new rows will automatically have values from the sequence assigned to it._ Thus has the same *gap* issue.